# Create ECharts based on the array length

Tags: angularjs, echarts, apache-echarts

I am using ECharts to create pie charts and the number of charts to be created depends on the length of the object as this object contains the data of the chart.

This is how my object looks. Pie chart is created with `query_result`  and `query_result`:

```
[
    {
        "request_id": "88f9f19a-eb25-4505-8482-c0a59d97a0da",
        "query_time": "2022-06-29T12:14:13.684Z",
        "query_result": 35,
        "query_total": 150,
    },
    {
        "request_id": "08c8736e-1e3d-4bd1-a041-1e31a1467f38",
        "query_time": "2022-06-29T12:14:13.684Z",
        "query_total": 100,
        "query_result": 60,
    },
    {
        "request_id": "b310641a-a415-41e4-9516-821d1956dd79",
        "query_time": "2022-06-29T12:14:13.684Z",
        "query_result": 20,
        "query_total": 100,
    }
]
```

How do I do this?

I am able to create ECharts for an object with constant number of elements. But because this number is not constant in my case, it is challenging.

Comment: So in your example you need 3 individual pie charts, or 1 pie chart with 3 slices?

Comment: I need 3 individual pie charts.